# Doctrine - OneToMany relation, all result row doesn't fetch in object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, hydration

I try to get all my objects DemandCab with their children object (DecisionCab).

My 2 entities

```
/**
 * DemandCab.
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DemandCabRepository")
 */
class DemandCab
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @var DecisionCab
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\My\CabBundle\Entity\DecisionCab", mappedBy="demandCab")
     */
     private $decisionsCab;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="datetime")
     */
     private $startDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
     private $endDate;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="followup", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
     private $followup;

    /**
     * @var InfoCab
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\My\CabBundle\Entity\InfoCab", inversedBy="demandsCab")
     */
     private $infoCab;

}

/**
 * DecisionCab.
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DecisionCabRepository")
 */
 class DecisionCab
 {
     /**
      * @var int
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
      * @var DemandCab
      *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\My\CabBundle\Entity\DemandCab", inversedBy="decisionsCab")
      */
     private $demandCab;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="decision", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
     private $decision;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="motif", type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     */
     private $motif;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $role;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
     private $date;

    /**
     * @var DemandCab
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\My\CabBundle\Entity\DemandCab", inversedBy="decisionsCab")
     */
     private $demandCab;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\My\CabBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="decisionsCab")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

In my DemandCabRepository

```
public function findAllCompleted(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("dem");
    $qb->select('dem, dec');
    $qb->leftJoin("dem.decisionsCab", "dec");
    $qb->andWhere("dem.completed = 1");
    $qb->orderBy("dem.startDate", "DESC");

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

My DemandCab data

[image: My DemandCab data]

My DecisionCab data

[image]

When i dump result, only 2 decisions appear ...
[image]

... whereas when i use `getArrayResult`, i have my 4 decisions ...
[image]

The query is good but i dont understand why hydration remove DecisionCab object with attribute `decision` at 0 or 1 (only null are display).

I would like to understand why and is there a solution to get DemandCab object with all DecisionCab children object.

Thanks

Comment: Which doctrine version are you using?

Comment: I use version 2.6 of Doctrine

Comment: Can you also add all the fields for your entities? One of them could be the cause of the improper hydration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue, but I am not sure if this is your case.

Anyway, my assumption is that you query the **demand** Entity joined with **decision** relation at least once with the help of a query builder. Maybe this is done in your action, in an event listener or somewhere else in your code.

So you may have something like:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(DemandCab::class)->createQueryBuilder("dem");
$qb->select('dem, dec');
$qb->leftJoin("dem.decisionsCab", "dec");

$qb->andWhere("dec.decision IS NULL");
$qb->orderBy("dem.startDate", "DESC");

$results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); // <-- the decisionsCab collection is hydrated but filtered

$qb2 = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(DemandCab::class)->createQueryBuilder("dem");
$qb2->select('dem, dec');
$qb2->leftJoin("dem.decisionsCab", "dec");

$qb2->andWhere("dem.completed = 1");
$qb2->orderBy("dem.startDate", "DESC");

    $q = $qb2->getQuery();
    //$q->setHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true);

    $results = $q->getResult();
```

The issue is in **Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator**, it has the property "**initializedCollections**" where already initialized collections are kept and the collections are hashed by the parent entity type and the entity itself. Unfortunately in the above case, the heydrator does not understand that the collection is filtered in the 1st query and uses it in the 2nd query in order to avoid rehydration.([github link](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php#L348))

**The solution** is to cause the query builder to **refresh**. Try the code:

```
$qb->orderBy("dem.startDate", "DESC");
$q = $qb->getQuery();
$q->setHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true);    // <-- Tell the hydrator to refresh
return $q->getResult();
```

Comment: You're the best ! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

First you have initialize your class with the relation ManyToOne with an ArrayCollection.

And you don't need any of this 'DemandCabRepository'. All the work is done by Doctrine