# "NOT EXISTS" Query with Many to Many Relation Doctrine Symfony3

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, php-7, symfony-3.3

I would like to build a query that brings me all the games for a logged in user that he has not yet joined. For this I have built these 2 Entities. They are connected by many to many.

```
class Game
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var Users[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Domain\Entity\User",
     *     inversedBy="user",
     *     fetch="EAGER"
     * )
     */
    private $users;
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getUsers() : array
{
    return $this->users->getValues();
}

/**
 * @param User $users
 */
public function setUser($users)
{
    if(is_array($users)){
        /** @var User $user */
        foreach ($users as $user){
            $this->users->add($user);
        }
    } else {
        $this->users->add($users);
    }
}
}
```

And the User Entity

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

The Entities has more attributes but i think they are not important. 
Also I tried these Query, but it doesn't work.

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return array
 */
public function fetchAllNonActivatedWhereYouNotJoin(User $user): array
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');
    $qb->select('g')
        ->innerJoin('g.users', 'u')
        ->where('u.id != :user')
        ->andWhere('g.activate = 0')
        ->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
        ->getQuery()->getResult();


    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Does anyone know a solution? Its Symfony 3 and Doctrine in PHP 7.1

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @maiorano84 it works, but it returns all games. But it shuld return only the games the user dosent join

Comment: 1.If you want the games the user has not join, the query seems to be ok. 
_"I would like to build a query that brings me all the games for a logged in user that he has not yet joined"_
2.If the user is not joined it should not have any game. please check your bussiness logic, your post reads that you want to bring **all the games**.
3.The query works for both logic

Comment: You are after a RIGHT JOIN. Search on SO how to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is **left join the 2 entities** starting from the **game repository** as you do, with a **join condition** to the logged in user and have a condition that **users is empty**:

```
$qb->leftJoin('g.users', 'u', Join::WITH, 'u.id = :user')
->andWhere('g.activate = 0')
->having('COUNT(u) = 0')
->groupby('g')
->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This works because of doctrine hydration, which hydrates the **users** property on the limited joined query(in this case each game will either have the logged in user or not in the users collection).

There are also [other ways to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514019/doctrine-2-dql-select-rows-where-a-many-to-many-field-is-empty/39998912#39998912)

Be careful with this if you are doing **consecutive queries with the query builder**, as the entity manager keeps references to the already hydrated relations. [Reference of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48510697/4448410)

Comment: Thanks ! That Works!