# Doctrine: select rows that are related to another table

Tags: doctrine

I have two tables: assignment and file that is related to assignment. I would like to get rows of assignment that are related to any row of file applying the where sentence.

```
$querybuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('query');
$querybuilder
    ->select('assignment')
    ->from(AssignmentReadModel::class, 'assignment')
    ->innerJoin('assignment.files', 'files')
    ->where('files.name=:archivo')
    ->setParameter('archivo', 'practica');

$data = $querybuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
$files = $data[0]->files();
var_export($files->count());
```

With this query I'm getting all the files when it should only get only one file "practica". When I execute "$files->count()" doctrine is doing a extra query to get all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In query, no columns of the **files** entity are selected, so this is not part of the result rows and thus the relation is **not hydrated**.

To get the **filtered files**, select also the **files** relation:

```
$querybuilder
->select('assignment')
->addSelect('files')
```

### **A word of caution**

Once a relation has been hydrated, this hydrated collection is used for this entity for other queries(reference [all result row doesn't fetch in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152609/doctrine-onetomany-relation-all-result-row-doesnt-fetch-in-object/48510697#48510697), unless you choose to

1) **refresh** the collection:

```
$em->refresh($assignment);
```

and also include refrech option on cascade operations of the relation definition:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="assignment", cascade={"refresh"})
```

or

2) when using query builder to set:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

$querybuilder->setHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true);    // <-- Tell the hydrator to refresh
```

Comment: So every time I want to filter by diferentes filters I have to refresh it,  right?

Comment: Yes,at the moment you have to. Maybe in the future something changes at doctrine and it can identify different filters.